# Strange bug in widget in Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to write home screen widget. On the widget there are few `TextViews` with two `ImageButtons`. One is for refreshing and second for opening the settings window.

The problem is that it is working on Android 4.2.2 and not working on Android 2.3.3.

Everything looks fine. but when buttons are pressed they don't work. The most interesting thing is that it is only happening on the first instance of the widget. When second is added everything works ok.

This is a small part of my code, which is used to make update and at this point it is definitely not working in Android 2.3.3:

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "onUpdate");
        // Get all widgets ids
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
                DataAppWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        Log.d(TAG, "widgets id: " + allWidgetIds.length);

        for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Widget: " + widgetId);
            // Get remote view
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_layout);

            refreshIntentSend(context, remoteViews, allWidgetIds, widgetId);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

    /**
     * Set up and add intent to button to refresh given widget
     */
    private void refreshIntentSend(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews,
            int[] allWidgetIds, int widgetId)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, DataAppWidgetProvider.class);
        i.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imb_refresh,pi);
        Log.d(TAG, "refresh: " + widgetId + " remoteViews: " + remoteViews);
    }
```

imb is `ImageButton`.

Does someone see something wrong here?

EDIT:

Checking in onReceive I get quite interesting outcome. if it looks like this:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"intent: " + intent.getAction());
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
```

or like this:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"intent: " + intent.getAction());
        if(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"Action");
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
```

The LogCat looks something like this:

```
DataAppWidgetProvider(411): intent: android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE
DataAppWidgetProvider(411): Action
```

When there is no override, or it is after super in `onReceive` the `onUpdate` is not called at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an Open android issue

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8889

Work around -- CTRL + F11 on Emulator or changing the orientation of the device